# Mountpoint from a filename - portable way

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems, mount, mount-point

Want make a script (called `getmpoint`) what will return the mountpoint from ANY filename.

The 1st idea, like: parsing output form the `df` or parsing `fstab` is not as easy as seems, because for example:

```
getmpoint ../../../some/path/tmp/somefile
getmpoint /tmp/somesymlink   #and want get the mountpoint where the real file is
getmpoint /
```

I have some idea by using `stat` (getting the device) - but i'm lost. Need some pointers how to solve this.

Another question is than the `stat` command is different on [Freebsd-stat](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/stat/) and [Linux-stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat). Is here any portable way?

Similarly, what about:

```
getmpoint /some/real/path/up/to/here/but/nonexistent_file
```

would be nice to get a mountpoint only from the path - without the file existence - so without `stat`.

Any advices? (I'm probably able make a script myself - but need some guide how to do ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

*getmpoint.sh, expects the filenames as param*

```
#!/bin/bash

for path
do
    orig=$path

    #find the existing path component
    while [ ! -e "$path" ]
    do
        path=$(dirname "$path")
    done

    #get a real file from a symlink
    [ -L "$path" ] && path=$(readlink "$path")

    # use "portable" (df -P)  - to get all informatons
    # 512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
    read s512 used avail capa mounted <<< $(df -P "$path" | awk '{if(NR==2){ print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}}')

    echo "Filename: $orig"
    echo "Mounted: $mounted"
    echo "Available blocks: $avail"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution and portable too.

Comment: Hehe, nice edit :) Would upvote it if I could ;). Note that I first tried something like `df ... | tail -n 1` and was astonished that this didn't worked. However the `sed '1d'` should work well although I liked the `awk` solution more as it gives you the sixth column (mounted) without additional parsing effort

Comment: Yeah - and the read has usual problems when the filename contains spaces, so back to the awk :)